# HTML Validation not working for only characters in input type textbox

Tags: html, validation

```
     <input type="text" name="company_reg_no" id="company_reg_no" 
      pattern="[A-Za-z]+"
    class="form-control required" minlength="3" maxlength="25" >
```

Pattern  pattern="[A-Za-z\s]+" and Pattern  pattern="[A-Za-z]"also tried

the pattern validation is not working

Comment: As it works only using HTML5 and is not supported by Safari at all I don't think it's good practice to use it

Comment: Try adding required attribute to it like:      <input type="text" name="company_reg_no" id="company_reg_no" 
      pattern="[A-Za-z]+"
    class="form-control required" minlength="3" maxlength="25"  required>

Comment: @NoOorZ24 2 its not working

Comment: you can just use java-script to validate form elements before submission. Don't forget that you have to validate them on server-side anyways so it's not even that important to validate them before submission

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JavaScript,, then try this

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
        try {
            if (window.event) {
                var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e) {
                var charCode = e.which;
            }
            else { return true; }
            if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123 || charCode = 32))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.Description);
        }
    }

</script>

<input type="text" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this);" />
```

Comment: he asked html pattern validation

Comment: @lalithkumar No, he didn't - he stated that it's not working

Comment: oh ok @NoOorZ24